# Jade - how to have extra href tag inside href tag

Tags: pug

```
a.item(href="/more/" + article.id)
  div 
    p brief summary
    a(href="/more/" + article.id)
```

It gave me the weird broken layout if I try to insert extra href tag inside href tag. Checked view source and it showed that last href tag is outside div. Not sure how I can have a href tag inside a href tag in Jade template.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me. I suggest checking your indentations, making sure that you are always using spaces, and never using tabs. (Perhaps that nested Anchor tag is using a tab instead of four spaces.) However, do note that regardless of the output, nested Anchor tags are invalid HTML and not HTML compliant.

This code was tested using the online Jade processor: http://jade-lang.com/demo/

Using the Jade code:

```
a.item(href="/more/" + article.id)
  div 
    p brief summary
    a(href="/more/" + article.id)
```

Using a JSON object of:

```
{
  article: {
    id: 'foo'
  }
}
```

The Jade output was:

```
<a href="/more/foo" class="item">
  <div> 
    <p>brief summary</p><a href="/more/foo"></a>
  </div></a>
```

Regarding the Invalid HTML:

As noted in the HTML4 specification, an Anchor tag cannot be nested within another Anchor tag: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2

`<!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->`

The same also holds with the HTML5 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a

`The interactive element a must not appear as a descendant of the a element.`

Comment: since a tag cannot be nested inside a tag, I chose to have only one a tag. but thank you for your help